# How can I use \raggedright with indent of 1.27 cm? I saw a post about this somewhere but it did not work

Tags: indentation

[image]

[image]

```
   \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{1.6em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
%Border
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
%Double spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedright


%font

\usepackage{times} 

\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}


\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{\underline{Microeconomics Commentary}}

\indent Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: if you mean you want paragraph indentation just on the first word of each paragraph, move the setting of `\parindent` anfter `\raggedright` as `\raggedright` sets it to 0pt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you know why its like this? The formatting in word is different than the one in latex despite same font size, font style, and indent size.

Comment: why should the formatting be like Word? raggedright is normally set with no indent, and a vertical space betwen paragraphs,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle

Is ragged right not the same thing as align left? Then, I added an indent on the first word in a paragraph. I need the formatting to be like Word so do you know how I could do this ? 

By formatting I just mean left aligned and first word of paragraph indented. Im not too sure how raggedright changes from left aligned.

Comment: they mean the same thing and as I say if you want an indent just specify that after the `\raggedright`. I don't know anything about word, but the formatting will be different in any case the line breaking and page breaking algorithims are quite different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah alright thanks. I thought they used the same line breaking system. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`\raggedright` sets `\parindent` to 0pt so if (unusually) you want indentation with  ragged setting, simply move

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
```

after

```
\raggedright
```

It is also unusual to use indentation with a positive `\parskip`. Usually you mark paragrahs with a vertical space or a horizontal indent, you don't really need both.